# Views params not shared between views Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, breadcrumbs

I've a problem with yii2 breadcrumbs, I need to implement a 3 steps registration on my site and I'll like to obtain breadcrumbs like

> Home Page / Step1 / Step2 / Step3

I've a dedicated controller which handle 3 steps with 3 actions, every time I call a distinct view for distinct step.
The main action controller:

```
$model = new SignupForm();
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
    return $this->redirect([Url::to('destinations'), 'card_code' => $model->client_code]);
}
return $this->render('index', ['model' => $model]);
```

The destinations action:

```
$model = new DestinationsForm();
if ($client_code = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('card_code')) {
    $addresses = $model->findByClientCode($client_code);
    return $this->render('destinations', ['model' => $model, 'addresses' => $addresses]);
}else if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
    return $this->redirect([Url::to('udata'), 'dest' => $model->destination]);
}
return $this->redirect(Url::to('index'));
```

In both views I've put this code for breadcrumbs:

```
$this->title = 'Page title';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
```

and in the main layout (views/layout/main.php)

```
<?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
]) ?>
```

Now my problem is the breadcrumbs was rendered like

> Home page / Step1

and for the step2

> Home page / Step2

How I can fix the problem?
Thanks

Comment: So, You Have 3 Different Actions For Step1, Step2, Step3 or What?

Comment: @NanaPartykar Yes, the action which serve Step3 isn't implemented yet, when I go from step1 to step2 the breadcrumbs are "Home Page / Step2" instead "Home page / Step1 / Step2"